# Return tree structure flow from a linking table of nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to output the tree flow of a table containing links between nodes

```
Input Table:
LocationType,Source, Location

'B','A1','B1'
'C','B1','C1'
'D','C1','D1'
'E','D1','E1'
'C','B2','C2'
'D','B3','D3'
'E','D4','E4'
'B','A5','B5'
'B','A5','B6'
'C','B6','C6'
'D','C6','D7'
'D','C7','D7'
'E','D7','E8'
'D',null,'D9'
'E','D9,'E9'
```

Assumptions that can be made:

> 'A' being the earliest root for a tree but root can start at any node
>
> Tree flows one direction ie. A < B < C < D < E
>
> No backwards linking e.g. B can link to D but D cannot link to A, B or
>   C
>
> Starting position is not always the same (not always A). Ending
>   position is not always the same (can end sooner than E)
>
> Multiple children can exist e.g. A5 to B5, A5 to B6
>
> A node can have multiple sources e.g. C6 to D7, C7 to D7.  Source can
>   be null. Location can never be null

Prefer best SQL performance as lots of data exist.

Desired Output: (order not important)

```
Columns: A,B,C,D,E

'A1','B1','C1','D1','E1'
null,'B2','C2',null,null
null,'B3',null,'D3',null
null,null,null,'D4','E4'
'A5','B5',null,null,null
'A5','B6','C6','D7','E8'
null,null,'C7','D7','E8'
null,null,null,'D9','E9'
```

Test Data Generation

```
CREATE TABLE Links
(
  [LocationType] CHAR(1) ,
  [Source] VARCHAR(10) ,
  [Location] VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO Links VALUES ('B','A1','B1')
INSERT INTO Links VALUES ('C','B1','C1')
INSERT INTO Links VALUES ('D','C1','D1')
INSERT INTO Links VALUES ('E','D1','E1')
INSERT INTO Links VALUES ('C','B2','C2')
INSERT INTO Links VALUES ('D','B3','D3')
INSERT INTO Links VALUES ('E','D4','E4')
INSERT INTO Links VALUES ('B','A5','B5')
INSERT INTO Links VALUES ('B','A5','B6')
INSERT INTO Links VALUES ('C','B6','C6')
INSERT INTO Links VALUES ('D','C6','D7')
INSERT INTO Links VALUES ('D','C7','D7')
INSERT INTO Links VALUES ('E','D7','E8')
INSERT INTO Links VALUES ('D',null,'D9')
INSERT INTO Links VALUES ('E','D9','E9')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you'll need to make use of a recursive CTE (common table expression).

This query is using the data you've provided and matches the example output you provided:

```
;WITH [cte_root_items] AS
    ( -- find the root items and use ROW_NUMBER() to create an identifier for each root item
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT([Source], LEN([Source]) - 1) AS INT), [Source]) [SourceIdentifier],
            [Source],
            [Location]
        FROM [dbo].[Links]
        WHERE   [Source] NOT IN (SELECT [Location] FROM [dbo].[Links] WHERE [Source] IS NOT NULL)
    ),
[cte_recursion] AS
    ( -- recursively iterate through tree until all child items for each root item are found
        SELECT
            [SourceIdentifier],
            [Source],
            [Location]
        FROM [cte_root_items]

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            A.[SourceIdentifier],
            A.[Source],
            B.[Location]
        FROM [cte_recursion] A
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Links] B
        ON      A.[Location] = B.[Source]
    ),
[cte_root_items_combined_with_recursion] AS
    ( -- append the root items to the items found during recursion
        SELECT
            [SourceIdentifier],
            [Source] [Location]
        FROM [cte_root_items]

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            [SourceIdentifier],
            [Location]
        FROM [cte_recursion]
    )
SELECT -- pivot the data into columns A-E
    MAX(CASE WHEN [Location] LIKE 'A%' THEN [Location] ELSE NULL END) [A],
    MAX(CASE WHEN [Location] LIKE 'B%' THEN [Location] ELSE NULL END) [B],
    MAX(CASE WHEN [Location] LIKE 'C%' THEN [Location] ELSE NULL END) [C],
    MAX(CASE WHEN [Location] LIKE 'D%' THEN [Location] ELSE NULL END) [D],
    MAX(CASE WHEN [Location] LIKE 'E%' THEN [Location] ELSE NULL END) [E]
FROM [cte_root_items_combined_with_recursion]
GROUP BY 
    [SourceIdentifier]
ORDER BY -- ordering data just to match example output, although noted as not important
    [SourceIdentifier];
```